XyJax fails to draw dashed line
The code
$$\xymatrix{
&\ar@{.}[d]\\
1&2
}$$

produces a dashed line above 2 in xypic:     texlive
so it is valid xypic code.
But it causes an error in XyJax (an implementation of xypic in Javascript. Examples)


<script>
  MathJax = {
    loader: {
      load: ['[custom]/xypic.js'],
      paths: {custom: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/sonoisa/XyJax-v3@3.0.1/build/'}
    },
    tex: {
      packages: {'[+]': ['xypic']}
    }
  };
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3.1.4/es5/tex-chtml.js"></script>

$$\xymatrix{
&\ar@{.}[d]\\
1&2
}$$



Error: SyntaxError } expected but [ found. Parse error at or near &\ar@{.}[d]\\.
(A temporary workaround is to add {} before \ar@{.}[d])
Can you locate the Javascript code that causes the error?
I tried to read the source of XyJax parser.

Sounds like you should ask the XyJax people forst? https://sonoisa.github.io/xyjax-v3/xyjax-v3.html lists a number of options.
